# Error message when read multiple text elements using selenium

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am clicking on a certain link and would like to read all the text in a given class and return that as a row in pandas dataframe

This is the code I have

```
page_link = 'http://beta.compuboxdata.com/fighter'
wait = WebDriverWait(cdriver,10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'s2id_autogen1'))).send_keys('Deontay Wilder')
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'select2-result-label'))).click()
while True:
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'view_more'))).click()
    try:
        element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'view_more')))
        element.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        break
fights['fighters'] = wait.until(EC.find_element_by_class_name((By.CLASS_NAME,'col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4'))).text
```

This, however returns the error message:

```
TimeoutException: Message:
```

I have also tried using xpath but still getting the same error message:

```
fights['fighters'] = wait.until(EC.find_element_by_xpath((By.CLASS_NAME,'//div[@class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"]/div'))).text
```

I specifically want to get this data:
[image]

As requested this is the full traceback

```
<ipython-input-94-e2b36e136c00> in <module>
     14 wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'select2-result-label'))).click()
     15 while True:
---> 16     wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'view_more'))).click()
     17     try:
     18         element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'view_more')))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     78             if time.time() > end_time:
     79                 break
---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     81 
     82     def until_not(self, method, message=''):

TimeoutException: Message:
```

This is the source HTML
[image: source]

Update

I tried adding a for loop to read multiple text elements, but still getting the same error

```
elements = wait.until(EC.find_element_by_class_name((By.CLASS_NAME,'col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4')))
for e in elements:
    print(e.text)
```

Comment: can you post the html page source and the complete stack trace? If you are trying to collect multiple elements on a page, then you have to use 'find_elements' method rather than 'find_element'

Comment: @Sureshmani I have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution. The Timeout exception will be handled here.

```
    age_link = 'http://beta.compuboxdata.com/fighter'
driver.get(age_link)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'s2id_autogen1'))).send_keys('Deontay Wilder')
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'select2-result-label'))).click()
#Click on View More until it exists
while True:
    try:
        element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'view_more')))
        print("Clicking on View More")
        element.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        break
fighters = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='row row-bottom-margin-5']/div[2]")
#fighters = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4")
print(len(fighters))
# Print all the fighter names
for fighter in fighters:
    print(fighter.text)
```

Comment: Thanks, doesn't seem to be printing out anything though

Comment: @Emm See updated answer. This is now printing the fighter details.

Comment: thanks, why does it work with 'xpath' and not with 'by_class_name' ?

Comment: it was throwing the error Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted. so i have tried with xpath.